# Send message from Browser to Unity3D

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am trying to send a message to my Unity3D WebGl app.

The controller of my GameObject "Player" looks basically like this:

```
public class color : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start ()
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
    }

    public void green(string s)
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
    }
}
```

and my Javascript method like this:

```
function SaySomethingToUnity() {
    SendMessage("Player", "green", "teeeext");
}
```

But when I call it nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? Could be a potential Security Sandbox Violation if you are testing locally. Firefox sometimes lets this slide, but not always. This Violation usually fails silently as well.

Comment: When you call `SaySomethingToUnity()` in your browser, can you use the Console (F12) and tell us if there are any messages?

Comment: I am using firefx right now beacuse on chrome i can`t test it without a server as far as I understood. In the beginning i had this error: Invoking error handler due to
ReferenceError: SendMessage is not defined 
But its gone now.
because I read somehwere that it  only works if i put "Enable Exception" in Publishing Settings to none.

Comment: How and when do you call `SaySomethingToUnity` function?

Comment: I call it like this:
 <script type="text/javascript">
          SaySomethingToUnity();
    </script>
at the end of my body in the html

Comment: The problem is likely that the page has not finished loading before you called that function. You have to implement a method to find out if the page has finished loading before calling any function in your game.

Comment: Yep. That was the Problem. Unity didnt finish loading :)
Thanks a lot

Comment: The browser's console helps a lot. This ReferenceError, as @Programmer pointed, was being raised because the method was not defined yet (actually he should post as answer). If this project might grow, I'd consider doing what I suggested below. Good luck!

Comment: @Mary When replying to people under your post, please use the @  sign or people won't be notified. I wasn't notified in your last 2 comments. I put that as answer to alert people that will have problems with this later on.You can accept it if you want

Comment: @Alisson just did. Thanks for notifying me about that. I had a feeling that was the problem but wasn't sure.

Comment: if the function has been called, but nothing happen, then try click the webgl frame with your mouse so it will change the focus. if it suddenly working(color change), then the real problem is focus. because i had that issue before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Decided to post the comment answer as the answer for people that will have this problem in the future.*

The page must finish loading before calling any function from Unity or else it won't work. When Unity is not yet done loading, the `Objects` that you want to send message to does **not** exist. Error will be thrown because of this or it will silently fail if `Exception` is disabled. So you must wait for some time before calling Unity function from Unity.

Comment: It didnt throw any errors in my case, but it was the Problem :)

Comment: @MaryLu I guess that depends on the version of Unity you have. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to put this option inside your own game, but if you really need to make an external script/app (like some website hosted somewhere) talk to unity, it should be done via an API.

Create an API with your preferred backend (PHP, ASP.NET WebAPI, Node.JS), expose a method `ReceiveMessageFromExternalSource()` so you can call from your javascript using a post request (using proper security), store it somewhere (either a database or any other persistance engine), then use your Unit3D app to call this same API using `WWWForm()`, to get said value. To avoid calling the server from Unity all the time looking for updated values, and make things work in "real time", I'd suggest you study things like WebSocket to make your server send a Signal to Unity, or even implementing a small server with Unity.

Comment: Your suggestion is very good, but anyway it is still possible to talk from browser to unity3d wbegl app. And OPs code sample should work, unless he is not calling SaySomethingToUnity, or is not using generated by unity3d js code with SendMessage implementation.

Comment: I am callling the method. so that shouldnt bethe reason. 
"or is not using generated by unity3d js code with SendMessage implementation."
About that part i'm not actually sure. I dont really know how to check that. The stuff i read so far just said it's supposed to have that methode.

Comment: my main Problem is that I don't want Unity to ask for data. In the end the application is supposed to show different motions from our database. so whenever you klick on a file/motion on the html page it is supposed to inform the Unity app to display that motion.

Comment: @MaryLu I understand. May I ask what exactly are these file/motion a user can click? Are they html components (like buttons?). If so, why don't you put these components inside your unity app?

Comment: They are basically buttons, but in form of preview gifs of the search results the user can get from our  database. But the problem is that those might change if the user types in new search criterias. So I'd have the same problem again, or I'd have to integrate the whole search in Unity. But I am nor sure if the integration of the whole database search in Unity would be the best option.